# Designation of algorithms performing automatic learning

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Can any algorithm that performs automatic learning be called a "machine learning algorithm"? Or is this designation is reserved to the known ML algorithms like SVM, Feature Selection... ?

Comment: ? What are you asking?

Comment: Automated learning can be "Unsupervised learning". Doesn't necessarily mean it's by a machine learning method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any algorithm that learns to do a task by itself and gets better at it is considered machine learning even if it just as simple as computing the joint probability. Only condition is automated learning, that's all.